singular subject + plural verb + plural predicate nominative ("The only garbage ARE his supporters.")
Please help in our argument: is it good English to say: The only garbage ARE his supporters?
If yes, what would the explanation be?


The only garbage ARE his supporters.

No, the verb has to agree with the subject garbage, singular.  We should say
The only garbage is his supporters.
Edit
If we do an inversion, we get
His supporters are the only garbage.
Wikipedia gives an example and explains inverse copular constructions:

The pictures are a problem.


A problem is/??are the pictures.


In the inverse copular constructions, the copula agrees with the singular predicative expression to its left as opposed to with the plural subject to its right.

inverse copular constructions
